# jQuery or JavaScript auto click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I auto click on the link on page load? I have been trying for ages but id does not work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leightbox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="leightbox.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<div class="content">
<p> <a href="#" class="lbOn" rel="pop02">Click here to activate leightbox popup.</a></p>
</div>



<!----------// POPUP (ON CLICK) //---------->
<div id="pop02" class="leightbox">
<a href="#" class="lbAction" rel="deactivate">×</a>

<div class="scrollbox">
<h1>This popup loads upon clicking a trigger link.</h1>
text</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: You have jQuery in the title and in the tags, but Prototype in the code. What do you want?

Comment: you can call the on click code on page load by $(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: i was trying someting else there then i forgot that is why i had Prototype

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You haven't provided your javascript code, but the usual cause of this type of issue is not waiting till the page is loaded.  Remember that most javascript is executed before the DOM is loaded, so code trying to manipulate it won't work.

To run code after the page has finished loading, use the $(document).ready callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#some-id').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 11):

First i tried with this sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('#upload-file').click(); 
});
```

It didn't work for me. Then after, tried with this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('#upload-file')[0].click(); 
});
```

No change. At last, tried with this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('#upload-file')[0].click(function(){
     }); 
});
```

Solved my problem. Helpful for anyone.

Comment: this is the solution)

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#some-id').trigger('click'); 
});
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.lbOn').click();
});
```

Suppose this would work too.

Answer (score 2):

In **jQuery** you can trigger a click like this:

```
$('#foo').trigger('click');
```

More here:

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

If you want to do the same using **prototype**, it looks like this:

```
$('foo').simulate('click');
```

Comment: Although .trigger() simulates an event activation, complete with a synthesized event object, it does not perfectly replicate a naturally-occurring event.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a popup work maybe? I don't know how to emulate click, maybe you can try to fire click event somehow, but I don't know if it is possible. More than likely such functionality is not implemented, because of security and privacy concerns.

You can use div with position:absolute to emulate popup at the same page. If you insist creating another page, I cannot help you. Maybe somebody else with more experience will add his 15 cents.