# Loading a page from a link that clicks a button on the loaded page automatically?

Tags: jquery, button, drupal

I am working on a Drupal site and have a page (we will call node--members.tpl.php) with buttons that can be clicked to show and hide content on that page.

I want to be able to link to members.tpl.php from other pages but have it so clicking a link automatically clicks a relevant button on the members.tpl.php node once it loads.

So if I'm coming from a link on a page about, say, Film Production, the members.tpl.php page loads up and clicks the button with an id of "Film Production".

I looked at some previous examples like [Jquery or javascript auto click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123516/jquery-or-javascript-auto-click) but for some reason this jQuery didn't work, and either way I want it to be called when just that one node page opens.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#Film Production').trigger('click');
});
```

So my questions are: why doesn't the above script doesn't work, and what approach can I take to do what I am trying to accomplish? Any kind of nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to make two separate DO MS interact. The only way I could think of achieving this is by using .pushstate and saving the previous url in a variable and using that variable to trigger the button if it equals whatever you set it to.

Comment: Thanks for your response Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to click a button? Why can't you pass something in the url?

```
http://yoursite.com/membership#film_production
```

Then you have javascript look at the url

```
Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
       urlInfo = parseURL(window.location.href);
       $(urlInfo.hash).show();         
  }
};

function parseURL(url) {
    var parser = document.createElement('a'),
        searchObject = {},
        queries, split, i;

    parser.href = url;
    // Convert query string to object
    queries = parser.search.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&');
    for( i = 0; i < queries.length; i++ ) {
        split = queries[i].split('=');
        searchObject[split[0]] = split[1];
    }
    return {
        protocol: parser.protocol,
        host: parser.host,
        hostname: parser.hostname,
        port: parser.port,
        pathname: parser.pathname,
        search: parser.search,
        searchObject: searchObject,
        hash: parser.hash
    };
}
```

The parseURL function comes from http://www.abeautifulsite.net/parsing-urls-in-javascript/. I have used it in a few projects now and it has worked very well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Quint! I'll give this a try and report back.