# Click event on body after page load in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to simulate up an automatic real click event on body after page load in Jquery?

This is not working as it needs me to manually click the body before the automatic event registers. I need to automatically simulate a real click event on page load.
Below is what I have tried:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
   $("body,html").click(function() {
     console.log("Automatic Click");
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery or javascript auto click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123516/jquery-or-javascript-auto-click)

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a click with:

```
 $( "body" ).trigger( "click" );
```

You can read more about it here:

https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work for what I am trying to do. The function I need it for only fires when it detects a page click hence the reason I am trying to simulate the click event

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**click()**](https://api.jquery.com/click/) like this:

```
$("body,html").click()
```

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("body,html").click(function() { // catch trigger the click
    console.log("Automatic Click");
  });
  $("body,html").click(); // trigger the click
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```